# Nintex .NET Framework RegEx Extract

Tags: .net, regex, nintex-workflow

I'm using Nintex Workflows and running into an issue trying to extract a alphanumeric value after the word `number:` using RegEx Action. I have two entries in document that I'm parsing.

```
Today's serial is number: A12345
```

This line appears twice in the email and I only watch to capture the first instance. Note: The alphanumeric value changes with each email it's not static.

Currently I'm using `(?<=number:\s) ([a-zA-Z0-9]+$)` however it doesn't match anything. When I do `(?<=number:\s)\w+` it matches the results both times.

What do I need to the working example to only collect the first match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the below regex,

```
(?s)^.*?number:\s([a-zA-Z0-9]+)
```

And get the string you want from group index 1. In  [`(?s)` dotall mode](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html), `^` matches the start of first line only.

**OR**

You could use the below  variable length look-behind based regex.

```
(?s)(?<=^.*?number:\s)[a-zA-Z0-9]+
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/zB3hI5/10)

Comment: This collects everything before `A12345` including it. It appears to stop when it reaches that however.

Comment: i asking you to print only the group index 1 only.

Comment: I'm sorry I have only been doing RegEx for a week could you expand on your answer please?

Comment: The second option your provided returns both entries within the email. The first one I do not understand what you mean by dotall mode

Comment: don't enable multiline modifier.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71088/discussion-between-jeremya1-and-avinash-raj).